# Change labels colors for radar chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I researched how to change label colors for my radar chart with chart.js.
I tried `scaleFontColor` but that doesn't work for me.

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["titi", "tata", "tutu"],

  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(51,49,90,0.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    data: [12, 18, 22]

  }]
};

var options = {
  responsive: true
};

var chart = document.getElementById('chart-area-x').getContext('2d');
new Chart(chart).Radar(data, options);
```

I want to put a specific color to "titi", "tata" and "tutu".

Comment: You may be able to just use a stylesheet. But without the markup I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change all the points label color use the option `pointLabelFontColor`.

If you want to change points label color individually you have to change chart.js since it does not implement this feature.

Here are the chart.js modifications needed to achieve change points label color individually:

Change chart.js lines:

from:

```
ctx.fillStyle = this.pointLabelFontColor;
```

to:

```
ctx.fillStyle = this.labels[i].fillStyle;
```

and

from:

```
ctx.fillText(this.labels[i], pointLabelPosition.x, pointLabelPosition.y);
```

to:

```
ctx.fillText(this.labels[i].text, pointLabelPosition.x, pointLabelPosition.y);
```

and

from:

```
textWidth = this.ctx.measureText(template(this.templateString, { value: this.labels[i] })).width + 5;
```

to:

```
textWidth = this.ctx.measureText(template(this.templateString, { value: this.labels[i].text })).width + 5;
```

Your HTML should be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Radar Chart - Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/Chart.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>

    <script>

        var data = {
            labels: [{
                text: "Eating", 
                fillStyle: "#01A4E0"
            }, {
                text: "Drinking", 
                fillStyle: "#FFE897"
            }, {
                text: "Sleeping", 
                fillStyle: "#428e2a"
            }, {
                text: "Designing", 
                fillStyle: "#6b3a0d"
            }, {
                text: "Coding", 
                fillStyle: "#0d5e6b"
            },{
                text: "Cycling", 
                fillStyle: "#450d6b"
            },{
                text: "Running", 
                fillStyle: "#6b0d36"
            }],         

            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
            }, {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
            }]
        };      

        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myRadarChart = new Chart(ctx).Radar(data);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you use the same chart.js for other radar charts that would still use labels as arrays you can add support for both ways of setting labels (array and object) replacing the mentioned chart.js lines using these instead:

```
ctx.fillStyle = this.labels[i].fillStyle ? this.labels[i].fillStyle : this.pointLabelFontColor;


ctx.fillText((this.labels[i].text ? this.labels[i].text : this.labels[i]), pointLabelPosition.x, pointLabelPosition.y);


textWidth = this.ctx.measureText(template(this.templateString, { value: (this.labels[i].text ? this.labels[i].text : this.labels[i]) })).width + 5;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help and the time you take for me! But I still have a problem.. 
My labels disappear whan I go on.. and I don't see my label's name when I'm on the point, I have " [object Object]: 25 " .. 
Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Hi Fernando, your solution works very well with chart.js 1.0 but not with 2.5... Do you have an idea of what I need to change ?

Answer (score 7):

[Based on Chart.js 2.7 documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#point-label-options) we may color labels with `options.scale.pointLabels.fontColor` :

```
        let tagsLabel = [ 'Axe1', 'Axe2', 'Axe3'];
        let chart = new Chart(targetNode, {
            type: 'radar',
            data: {
                labels: tagsLabel,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: [
                            0, 2,
                        ],
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    position: 'left'
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "It work's"
                },
                animation: {
                    animateScale: true,
                    animateRotate: true
                },
                scale: {
                    // ticks: {
                    //     backdropColor: 'red',
                    //     // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                    //     callback: function(value, index, values) {
                    //         return '$' + value;
                    //     }
                    // }
                    pointLabels: {
                        // callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        //     return '$' + value;
                        // }
                        fontColor: tagsLabel.map((lbl)=>randColor()),
                    },
                },
            }
        });
```